# select2 fullwidth in hidden div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

Assume I have a [select2 box](https://select2.org/getting-started/installation) inside a hidden div like this:

```
<form >   
 <div id="agent007">
  <select name="slimy" id="slimy">
   <option>Good</option>
   <option>Bad</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</form>
```

Where the selection box has full width and the div is hidden

```
select{
  width:100%
}

div{
  display:none;
}
```

When I make the div visible, then the selection box has no full width.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#slimy').select2();
  $('#agent007').show();
});
```

How can I make a [select2 box](https://select2.org/getting-started/installation) full width that was hiding in a invisible container?

Here is a [jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/26uroj7b/1/)

Comment: Adding some more explanation to the answers below on why doesn't the CSS that you've added work in setting the width: Inspect the `select` element that you've initialized **select2** to and you'll see that the `select` tag actually gets hidden and a new `span.select2-container` gets added and so the CSS `select { width: 100%; }` doesn't work. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [**a message**](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2045) from the author, it is evident that you need to destroy and reinitialise Select2. I had a similar scenario, nothing works other than reinitialising after destroying.

> You are probably going to want to destroy and then re-initialize the Select2, in order to get the width to be correct.
>
> Dynamically creating the options is not fully supported by Select2.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#faty").select2();
  $('#slimy').select2();
  $('#agent007').show();
  $('#slimy').select2("destroy").select2();
});
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#faty").select2();
  $('#slimy').select2();
  $('#agent007').show();
  $('#slimy').select2("destroy").select2();
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 100%
}

div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name="faty" id="faty">
    <option>Good</option>
    <option>Bad</option>
  </select>

  <div id="agent007">
    <select name="slimy" id="slimy">
      <option>Good</option>
      <option>Bad</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

**May be working in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/49zg2x6w/**

Comment: I think this answer is suboptimal - first of all the statement "nothing works other than reinitialising after destroying" is not true as demonstrated in my answer below. Secondly, the OP is not "dynamically creating the options" which is what the link you referenced is working around. There is a setting for width in the API and the OPs situation is exactly why it exists.

Comment: @billynoah Ah... Let me check it out too. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the width programmatically through the [Select2 Configuration API](https://select2.org/configuration/options-api).  The docs make it clear that sometimes this is your best option:

> Select2 will try to match the width of the original element as closely as possible. *Sometimes this isn't perfect, in which case you may manually set the width configuration option*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#slimy').select2({'width':'100%'});
  $('#agent007').css('display','block');
});
```

```css
select{
  width:100%
}

div{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<form >   
 <div id="agent007">
  <select name="slimy" id="slimy">
   <option>Good</option>
   <option>Bad</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</form>
```

*Note: due to a conflict between jQuery's `show()` and stack snippets, I used `css('display','block')` here as a workaround*

Answer (score 2):

If you want a CSS solution you can try the below:

```
select,
.select2-container { 
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

working fiddle link for you - https://jsfiddle.net/jithinrajpr7/26uroj7b/19/

Comment: why *-ve* please comment the issue so I can rectify the bug.

Answer (score -1):

Check the updated fiddle now.

[https://jsfiddle.net/26uroj7b/9/](http://Fiddle%20example)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#faty").select2();
    $('#agent007').show();
    $('#slimy').select2();
});
```

You can initialize the select2 after displaying `div`.

Comment: What if the scenario is dynamic? You gotta destroy and reinitialise.

Comment: but, as long as it is the first time only. Initializing after showing div would be fine, right? Your answer is good. I have just tried to put some other way.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but think about bigger applications who have a common selector, like `$(".select2").select2()` at the start. Something like that. Don't take it wrong, I am just telling you. `:)`

Comment: No buddy. I am learning, so trying to grasp more knowledge from friends like you. :) Got your point. ;)

Comment: Sure, any time... `:)`